# Implement jwt token validation in asp net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nestjs

I need to validate jwt token on several actions. The application uses .NET Framework 4.5.1. The token is generated in an application on NestJs. .Net application uses UseCookieAuthentication with custom CookieAuthenticationOptions. I'm new to .net, can you tell me where to start and what is better to use?

Comment: have a look at this https://jwt.io and this https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: @HariHaran thanks, for the quick response. I will try and let you know if it helped

Comment: @HariHaran yes, it worked. I used this library - System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt and I validated the token in the attribute above the method

Comment: Cool. Should i add it as an answer ? so you will reward me with a green check mark :p

Comment: @HariHaran yeah

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To know more authentication please read the below links

[JWT](https://jwt.io/)

[JWT Authentication Tutorial with Example API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)